# Flink 1.12.2 modifying savepoint locally - metadata has absolute paths

Tags: apache-flink

I'm trying to modify an existing savepoint, created with flink 1.12.2 & ververica 2.4.1, that was saved on S3.

The steps that I took are the following:

1. Copied the savepoint containing the '_metadata' and savepoint files from S3 to my local machine;
2. Opened the flink state and read the state of the operator I'm interested in;
3. Created and amended the dataset that I want to replace the state of that operator with ;
4. Trying to amend the state with the following code

```
BootstrapTransformation<AccountRegistrationInformation> transformation = OperatorTransformation
                    .bootstrapWith(accountDataSet)
                    .keyBy(acc -> acc.getBrand() + "-" + acc.getAccountId())
                    .transform(new AccountRegistrationBootstrapper());
Savepoint.load(executionEnvironment, "C:\\flinkState", new MemoryStateBackend())
                    .removeOperator("registration-processor")
                    .withOperator("registration-processor", transformation)
                    .write("C:\\flinkState\\transformed");
            executionEnvironment.execute();
```

When running the above code, it amends a subset of the dataset and flink throws the following exception.

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: \<redacted>\savepoint-c680a3-c178150a8b8d\32c44059-1f59-4091-bcb5-3e1efa369ec6 (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

When inspecting the _metadata, I noticed that it has absolute paths in S3:

```
s3://<redacted>/savepoint-c680a3-c178150a8b8d/32c44059-1f59-4091-bcb5-3e1efa369ec6
```

What I want is to save the amended savepoint to my local machine and then move that savepoint over to S3 manually so that flink can start with the amended state.

Can anybody share their experience with this?

Full exception:

```
10:09:25,169 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.state.heap.HeapKeyedStateBackend    [] - Initializing heap keyed state backend with stream factory.
10:09:25,170 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.state.heap.HeapKeyedStateBackendBuilder [] - Finished to build heap keyed state-backend.
10:09:25,171 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.state.heap.HeapKeyedStateBackend    [] - Initializing heap keyed state backend with stream factory.
10:09:25,176 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.partition.consumer.SingleInputGate [] - Converting recovered input channels (1 channels)
10:09:25,178 ERROR org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.DataSinkTask              [] - Error in user code: \<redacted>\savepoints\d18b311a-86e8-4406-93b5-f2b398c4257f\savepoint-c680a3-c178150a8b8d\32c44059-1f59-4091-bcb5-3e1efa369ec6 (The system cannot find the path specified):  DataSink (org.apache.flink.state.api.output.FileCopyFunction@da28d03) (1/1)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: \<redacted>\savepoints\d18b311a-86e8-4406-93b5-f2b398c4257f\savepoint-c680a3-c178150a8b8d\32c44059-1f59-4091-bcb5-3e1efa369ec6 (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_282]
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195) ~[?:1.8.0_282]
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138) ~[?:1.8.0_282]
    at org.apache.flink.core.fs.local.LocalDataInputStream.<init>(LocalDataInputStream.java:50) ~[flink-core-1.12.2.jar:1.12.2]
    at org.apache.flink.core.fs.local.LocalFileSystem.open(LocalFileSystem.java:134) ~[flink-core-1.12.2.jar:1.12.2]
    at org.apache.flink.core.fs.SafetyNetWrapperFileSystem.open(SafetyNetWrapperFileSystem.java:87) ~[flink-core-1.12.2.jar:1.12.2]
    at org.apache.flink.state.api.output.FileCopyFunction.writeRecord(FileCopyFunction.java:61) ~[flink-state-processor-api_2.11-1.12.2.jar:1.12.2]
    at org.apache.flink.state.api.output.FileCopyFunction.writeRecord(FileCopyFunction.java:34) ~[flink-state-processor-api_2.11-1.12.2.jar:1.12.2]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.DataSinkTask.invoke(DataSinkTask.java:235) [flink-runtime_2.11-1.12.2.jar:1.12.2]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:755) [flink-runtime_2.11-1.12.2.jar:1.12.2]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:570) [flink-runtime_2.11-1.12.2.jar:1.12.2]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_282]
10:09:25,223 WARN  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task                    [] - DataSink (org.apache.flink.state.api.output.FileCopyFunction@da28d03) (1/1)#0 (d4b998c90a0fc21a64f463b6476e85aa) switched from RUNNING to FAILED.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: \<redacted>\savepoints\d18b311a-86e8-4406-93b5-f2b398c4257f\savepoint-c680a3-c178150a8b8d\32c44059-1f59-4091-bcb5-3e1efa369ec6 (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_282]
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195) ~[?:1.8.0_282]
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138) ~[?:1.8.0_282]
    at org.apache.flink.core.fs.local.LocalDataInputStream.<init>(LocalDataInputStream.java:50) ~[flink-core-1.12.2.jar:1.12.2]
    at org.apache.flink.core.fs.local.LocalFileSystem.open(LocalFileSystem.java:134) ~[flink-core-1.12.2.jar:1.12.2]
    at org.apache.flink.core.fs.SafetyNetWrapperFileSystem.open(SafetyNetWrapperFileSystem.java:87) ~[flink-core-1.12.2.jar:1.12.2]
    at org.apache.flink.state.api.output.FileCopyFunction.writeRecord(FileCopyFunction.java:61) ~[flink-state-processor-api_2.11-1.12.2.jar:1.12.2]
    at org.apache.flink.state.api.output.FileCopyFunction.writeRecord(FileCopyFunction.java:34) ~[flink-state-processor-api_2.11-1.12.2.jar:1.12.2]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.DataSinkTask.invoke(DataSinkTask.java:235) ~[flink-runtime_2.11-1.12.2.jar:1.12.2]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:755) [flink-runtime_2.11-1.12.2.jar:1.12.2]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:570) [flink-runtime_2.11-1.12.2.jar:1.12.2]
10:09:25,224 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task                    [] - Freeing task resources for DataSink (org.apache.flink.state.api.output.FileCopyFunction@da28d03) (1/1)#0 (d4b998c90a0fc21a64f463b6476e85aa).
10:09:25,255 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task                    [] - MapPartition (2861c3d1e95af557df2962264aaf94ef) (6/8)#0 (ab4fcd08aa51c77eec1ac6d3c9fba2d3) switched from RUNNING to FINISHED.
10:09:25,255 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task                    [] - Freeing task resources for MapPartition (2861c3d1e95af557df2962264aaf94ef) (6/8)#0 (ab4fcd08aa51c77eec1ac6d3c9fba2d3).
10:09:25,255 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task                    [] - MapPartition (2861c3d1e95af557df2962264aaf94ef) (8/8)#0 (c0105262e4e271633df686c1b09476a9) switched from RUNNING to FINISHED.
10:09:25,256 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task                    [] - Freeing task resources for MapPartition (2861c3d1e95af557df2962264aaf94ef) (8/8)#0 (c0105262e4e271633df686c1b09476a9).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The absolute path in the _metadata could be a pointer to inline state: i.e.,  the state stored in _metadata directly. The state stored in data files should have relative paths.

What do you use in 'C:\flinkState' in your code and what do you see '<redacted>' in the FileNotFoundException? If they are sensitive, can you provide an example of them?

Also, did you try on a Linux machine?

Update:

The added stack trace is similar to the one in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-23429. Could you try to add the state processor API dependence from Flink **1.12.5** in your savepoint transformation job?

Comment: 1. What do you use in 'C:\flinkState' in your code? In the folder I have both the metadata and some other files. Reading the state is possible with using just the metadata.    2.  what do you see '<redacted>' in the FileNotFoundException? Flink is complaining that it can't find the path to the other files when executing. The path that it's complaining about is the same structure as the state files have in s3.     3. did you try on a Linux machine? I did not, I don't think it'll have any effect on the execution as I found these absolute paths in the _metadata itself

Comment: What the path in FileNotFoundException look like? Is it similar to "s3://bucket/path/to/object"?

Comment: Are you using [S3 entropy](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.12/deployment/filesystems/s3.html#entropy-injection-for-s3-file-systems)? It prevents savepoint relocation.

Comment: no, I do not use s3 entropy. the config is mostly the default flink config - only timings were changed. I'm puzzled because reading the state is fine and when I'm trying to amend the previous savepoint and save it to a different location it fails trying to find the non-metadata files in the s3 path. Creating a new savepoint from scratch is ok. would it be possible to run pointing directly at s3?

Comment: Could you share the full stacktrace of the FileNotFound exception?

Comment: amended the question with the full stacktrace

Comment: Thank you, the version update to 1.12.5 got me over the hump a bit. I was forced to add the flink-s3-fs-hadoop package to make it run as for some reason it wants to connect to s3. I am getting authentication errors but I'll figure out a way to grant access to s3 somehow. is my take on it that the state is not 'transportable' correct? In [the documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/ops/state/savepoints/) it says that it should be as it should contain relative paths. Would you happen to know if this a feature only for flink 1.13+?

Comment: The change that removed absolute paths from savepoints was made in Flink 1.11, but the documentation wasn't updated.

Comment: @DavidAnderson I upgraded the ververica cluster and flink to 1.13.2 and I am still seeing absolute paths in the savepoint. Is there any way to trigger savepoints with relative paths?

Comment: The idea is to have savepoint relocatable: it should contain only relative paths, except for those inline (i.e., embedded in _metadata) state which may have path like IDs. So, there is no intention to have an option to trigger savepoints with relative paths: either it is working, or it is a bug. If you could share an example of such a savepoint, I could give a deeper look.

Comment: BTW, were you able to work around it by adding s3 libs?